# Why does HAL_GetTick always return 0? (stm32, HAL)

Tags: stm32, hal

I am programming a state machine on an STM32G474RET6 board. The state should change from 0 to 5 after five seconds. Changing the states works quite well but when I wanted to test for the exact duration with HAL_GetTick, I discovered that HAL_GetTick always returns 0. I know that there is already a question for that but the answers all do not seem to work for me.

I have set up a project with everything I need to replicate the problem:
[image: Pinout config]

code in main.c:

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2023 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
uint8_t state = 0;
uint32_t timeStampsState0[3];
uint32_t debugVariable;
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
void checkIfStateMachineReachedStateOnTime(void);
/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  TIM2->SR &= ~(0x1UL);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    if(debugVariable != HAL_GetTick){
        debugVariable = HAL_GetTick();
    }
    if ((TIM2->SR & 0x1UL)!= 0x0UL){
        state = 1;
        TIM2->SR &= ~(0x1UL);
        timeStampsState0[1] = HAL_GetTick();
        timeStampsState0[2] = timeStampsState0[1] - timeStampsState0[0];
        checkIfStateMachineReachedStateOnTime();
    }
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief TIM2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 0 */

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 1 */
  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 15999;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 4999;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim2);

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
void checkIfStateMachineReachedStateOnTime(){
    float tolerance = 0.01; // 1%
    int deviation;

    if(timeStampsState0[3] < 5000){
        deviation = 5000 - timeStampsState0[3];
    }
    else{
        deviation = timeStampsState0[3] - 5000;
    }
    if(deviation > (tolerance*5000)){
        Error_Handler();
    }
}
/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();

  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

When using printf to look at the debugVariable, I can see that it is and stays 0.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
if(debugVariable != HAL_GetTick){
  debugVariable = HAL_GetTick(); }
```

first you compare debugVariable with the pointer to function `HAL_GetTick`, and as that is nonzero, the line which correctly calls the function is called unconditionally.

However, debugVariable is not volatile, so if you compile with non-zero optimization setting, the compiler optimizes out the assignment and the variable never changes.

Comment: Hm, this is weird. debugVariable is now 7500 and according to SWV, time is still at 0.000000 s. I would have expected 7500 increment to be 7.5 seconds or 0.000469 (my HCLK runs at 16 MHz)

Answer (score 0):

SysTick doesn't require to have clock supplied (being a core peripheral), so the next probable explanation is that the counter of systick is not enabled.

The other potential cause of the problem is that by default SysTick is configured to get ticks from external clock signal, **not** from the system (CPU) clock. This needs to be changed before SysTick is enabled.

The list of steps to make it work is the following:

1. Reload value and counter value are explicitly set upon power up just to be on the safe side (in dedicated SysTick registers).
2. SysTick gets clocked by System Clock, not by external clock signal, which would be the default configuration (in SysTick control register).
3. Optionally, SysTick exception (interrupt) is enabled (in SysTick control register).
4. Optionally, SysTick interrupt priority is set (in SCB core peripheral).
5. The counter is enabled (SysTick control register).

Comment: I don't Cube, but if `HAL_IncTick()` should be called in the `SysTick_Handler()` **interrupt** handler as @nielsen said above, then enabling systick interrupt in 3. is not optional. OTOH, all this should happen by Cube's _magic_, that's my understanding of Cube.

Comment: I don't understand how Cube has anything to do with it, I never mentioned it. Yes, depending on what you do, you may or may not need an interrupt. I described how to use SysTick in general and what can go wrong. In this specific case, it would make sense to have an interrupt and increment tick in the handler.

Comment: You did not mention Cube, but OP obviously uses it and relies upon it's _magic_ - namely that a Cube-provided variable otherwise hidden to user gets incremented in the SysTick (or some timer, if user choses so) interrupt every 1ms.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out that I only had to add `HAL_IncTick()` at the beginning of my while(1) loop. Not sure if that is the most elegant solution as I am just incrementing a random variable and could just define my own variable to increment?

Comment: `HAL_IncTick()` should be called in the `SysTick_Handler()` interrupt handler for the SysTick interrupt. It should normally count milliseconds. If you call it in the while loop, you have no control of the timing and timeouts in all HAL functions relaying on this, will not work.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do I then call the SysTick_Handler in every run of the while(1) loop?

Comment: No, you need to enable the SysTick interrupt. I do not have a STM32G4 setup at hand so I am not sure of the details, but you should be able to choose "System tick timer" as "time base" (under System Core->SYS ?) and check that this interrupt is enabled under NVIC where you should also be able to check that Code Generation is enabled for the "time base" interrupt. You may need to read up on [interrupts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt).